# EOF exception while sending file using UDP in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, tcp, udp

I was trying code from this link to send file using UDP,

[Emulate UDP Over TCP in multithread Server & Client](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/23088/java-multithreaded-file-server-and-client-emulate-tcp-over-udp)

But i'm getting EOF exception, I don't know why this code is giving such error, i doubled check the code , it seems right, I will be grateful for any help, i need this code for my thesis. Thanks in advance !!!!

```
  SERVER: Accepted connection.
  SERVER: receivedput C:\Users\Nika\workspace\test\10MB.txt
  THREAD: put C:\Users\Nika\workspace\test\10MB.txt
  *** Ready to receive file on port: 60829 ***
  *** The file will be saved as: Recieved-10MB.txt ***
  *** Expecting to receive: 104857600 bytes ***
  Mar 30, 2014 11:17:39 PM udpemu.CLIENTConnection run
  SEVERE: null
  java.io.EOFException
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(Unknown Source)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
  at udpemu.UDPFileReceiver.deserialize(UDPFileReceiver.java:126)
  at udpemu.UDPFileReceiver.<init>(UDPFileReceiver.java:52)
  at udpemu.CLIENTConnection.run(CLIENTConnection.java:60)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Did you close the object output stream?

Comment: @EJP AT server side or at client side ?